# Postgresql: use variable in role name

Tags: postgresql, roles, psql

I have many DB: A, B, C, etc.
For each DB, I created a readonly access role: A-ro, B-ro, C-ro.

Everytime I connect, I type:

```
SET ROLE 'A-ro';
```

Some DB names can be quite long, taping that everytime is not that cool; so, I'd like to create an alias in my .psqlrc, in order to type something like:

```
psql> :ro
```

I tried that with two things: current_database() and :DBNAME.
Problem: it seems I can not write something like:
SET ROLE (SELECT current_database() || '-ro');

And I can't write that either:

```
SET ROLE ':DBNAME-ro';
```

or

```
SET ROLE :DBNAME || '-ro';
```

I'm looking for the correct syntax.

Comment: You could use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). The downside is that you have to wrap this into a plpgsql function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mdlx answer, I dug into "intermediate variable" way.
Here is my working .psqlrc extract:

```
\set ROLE_RO '''':DBNAME-ro''''
\set ro 'SET ROLE ':ROLE_RO;
```

Switch to RO mode is working:

```
psql> :ro
SET
```